# Recursively delete empty folders in Lua

Tags: recursion, file-system, lua

I have written a script that run in [WingFTP Server](http://www.wftpserver.com/) which has a Lua scripting engine built in. The script recursively deletes empty folders except the specified root folder.

```
--Walks a file tree and delete empty folders except the root folder
function EmptyFolderDeleter(options)
    local rootPath = options.path
    local path = options.path

    function walk(path)
        local currentPath = path

        --cycle through the current directory, walking directories
        for dir in c_GetDir(currentPath) do
            local fullPath = currentPath..dir.."/"
            walk(fullPath)
        end

        --if we've got this far then we're at the bottom of the tree
        --there are no more directories to visit
        --now check if there is ANYTHING (file or folder) in the current folder 
        local empty = true
        for isdir, file in c_GetFileDir(currentPath) do
            empty = false
        end

        --now check the 'empty' flag and if the folder is the root
        if empty == true and currentPath ~= rootPath then
            c_RemoveFileDir(currentPath)
        end

    end
    walk(path)
 end
```

The script uses three custom Lua functions that are built into WingFTP:

`c_GetDir()` = an iterator that returns directory names as string

`c_GetFileDir()` = an iterator that returns directory and file names as strings. Also returns a boolean whether the returned string is directory or not.

`c_RemoveFileDir()` = Deletes the specified file or folder

My script can be called like so like so:

```
local root = "D:/Clients/"
for dir in c_GetDir(root) do
    EmptyFolderDeleter{path=root..dir.."/"}
end
```

Is there is simpler or more efficient way to recursively delete empty sub folders in Lua?

Is there anything I can do to improve code readability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not updating the variables `path`, `rootPath` and `currentPath` anywhere, use a single variable.

Define the function `walk` locally.

You can also break out of your `c_GetFileDir` loop once you've updated the `empty` flag. This will remove the time to iterate through all children of a directory.

> **The [help pages for WFTPServer](http://www.wftpserver.com/help/ftpserver/miscellaneous2.htm) have a 
>   different return values for `c_GetFileDir` than
>   yours!**

```
function EmptyFolderDeleter( options )
    local root = options.path

    local walk = function( path )

        --cycle through the current directory, walking directories
        for dir in c_GetDir( path ) do
            walk( path..dir.."/" )
        end

        --if we've got this far then we're at the bottom of the tree
        --there are no more directories to visit
        --now check if there is ANYTHING (file or folder) in the current folder 
        local empty = true
        for isdir, file in c_GetFileDir( path ) do
            empty = false
            break
        end

        --now check the 'empty' flag and if the folder is the root
        if empty and path ~= root then
            c_RemoveFileDir( path )
        end
    end

    walk( root )
 end
```

Comment: Regarding `c_GetFileDir` in the help pages: Yes I was scratching my head for ages and then I contacted WingFTP directly who confirmed that their help pages are in fact incorrect!

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I feel the readability of the code has been improved. 
Just one note: I like the the white spacing in the function parameters, e.g. `walk( root )` I have not seen this before and am surprised that I quite like it! How do you format functions with multiple parameters?

Comment: @chazjn `f( a, b, {1, 2, 3}, c, d )`